# Contextily Userwarning: The inferred zoom level of 31 is not valid for the current tile provider (valid zooms: 0 - 20)

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, contextily

I am trying to plot latitude and longitude coordinates on a contextily basemap but thus far have been unable to do so because the "inferred zoom level is not valid for the tile provider." [image]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(clip_businesses)

geometry1 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df1['Long'], df1['Lat'])]
gdflittleton = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=geometry1)

gdflittleton_web_mercator = gdflittleton.to_crs(epsg=3857)

# Create subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (10, 10))

gdflittleton_web_mercator.plot(ax = ax, marker = 'o', color = 'dodgerblue', markersize = 3)

ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs='EPSG:3857', source=ctx.providers.CartoDB.Voyager)
```

Even when I manually change the zoom level for the contextily map, I still am left with a blank slate. In short, I'm hoping to plot lat long coordinates over a contextily basemap.

Comment: The error message is probably misleading: based on your points, `contextily` computed a zoom level to nicely plot your map, but it tells you that the tile provider cannot provide tiles for such a zoom level. To give you an idea, it is a bit as if you were trying to represent an ant path and ask `contextily` to fetch a background from CartoDB. Your problem probably lies in the CRS management of your data.

Comment: Seeing your snippet of code, I am surprised you did not get an error on this line `gdflittleton_web_mercator = gdflittleton.to_crs(epsg=3857)` considering you did not set a CRS for `gdflittleton`, because it should not be able to change CRS if it has none defined. If it has one, which is it and where does it comes from? And most importantly, is it the right one? Answering that should help you solve your problem.